# How to remove an application "tile" from Anaconda Navigator Home tab

Tags: anaconda, navigator

I have a bunch of apps that I will never use (GLueviz, Orange3, Rstudio) that I would like gone from my Home tab.  They are not installed, but there is no way to remove the tile for the app.  The gear icon isn't going to do it for me.

I dug into the config file `~/.anaconda/navigator/anaconda-navigator.ini` and nothing obvious there.  Oddly it says that `vscode_enable = False` yet VS Code does appear as a tile.

I'm running 1.9.12 individual edition on MacOS Catalina.

Comment: Good question, it seems these applications are not "installed", but the tile cannot be removed. But the number is growing. Datalore and IBM Watson are pre-installed when Anaconda is updated, they can't be removed either. Obviously this navigator is used to promote products in the hard way. The whole "home" tab should be removed.

Answer (score 2):

On navigator 2.1.1, I was able to comment out the two lines for Datalore and IBM Watson in `~/opt/anaconda3/pkgs/anaconda-navigator-2.1.1-py39_0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/external_apps/__init__.py.`

```
    web_apps: 'typing_extensions.Final[typing.Mapping[str, WebAppInitializer]]' = {
        #'datalore': DataloreApp,  # noqa: F405
        #'ibm_watson': IBMWatsonApp,  # noqa: F405
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, unfortunately, nothing happened on my end. Any other ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  I edited the "__init__.py" file, restarted Navigator, and they tiles were gone.

Comment: I'll try it again

Comment: Did you have any success?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the Anaconda docs https://docs.anaconda.com/navigator/tutorials/custom-tiles/, you can create a yaml file that will allow you to disable some of the tiles.
In practice, I've found this works for some apps, but may not work for all.  For example, some of the gnuradio apps go away, but many do not (e.g., gnuradio-build-deps).

1. Create a yaml file at ~/.anaconda/navigator/applications/ (MacOS)
2. Add the code to disable an application from view:

```
glueviz:
     is_available: false
```

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 11, create a yaml file called "**hidden_apps.yaml**" located at "**%userprofile%.anaconda\navigator.anaconda\navigator\applications**" and select "**true**" or "**false**" for the appropriate app:

```
ibm_watson:
  is_available: false
pycharm_pro:
  is_available: false
deepnote:
  is_available: false
datalore:
  is_available: false
spyder:
  is_available: false
oracle:
  is_available: false
qtconsole:
  is_available: false
powershell_shortcut:
  is_available: false
dataspell:
  is_available: false
console_shortcut:
  is_available: true
vscode:
  is_available: true
notebook:
  is_available: true
jupyterlab:
  is_available: true
```

Answer (score 1):

A-Navigator 2.4.2 for Windows

File: C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\static\content\external_apps.yml

Remove or comment (with #'s) entire paragraph

datalore:
app_type: web_app
description: >
Kick-start your data science projects in seconds in a pre-configured environment. Enjoy coding assistance for Python, SQL, and R in Jupyter notebooks and benefit from no-code automations. Use Datalore online for free.
display_name: Datalore
image_path: datalore-icon.png
is_available: true
url: https:/ /www.anaconda.com/datalore_navigator

Answer (score 1):

A config.yaml file in the **"%userprofile%.anaconda\navigator.anaconda\navigator\applications"** folder works for me, but it seems that the number of spaces in front of `is_available: false`  required for this to work is exactly two. Multiple spaces and tabs did not work for me.

```
ibm_watson:
  is_available: false
```

You also need to get the name right, but i could not yet figure all of them out.